# Display selected value on dropdown in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-8

I have a dropdown in my edit form, but it doesn't display the selected value on the index.

[image: Dropdown box image]

```
 var ingredients=<?php echo $boms->load('rawMaterial') ?>;
 console.log('BillOfMaterials', ingredients);
```

[image]

I put `onClick=setIngredientsId` on my edit button.

```
function setIngredientsId(id){

        ingredients.forEach(element => {

            if(element.id==id){
                console.log('hello', element.raw_material)
                $('#modal-title-new-ingredients').html("Edit Ingredient")
                $('#bom_id').val(element.id);
                $('#ingredients').val(element.raw_material_id);
                $('#consumption').val(element.quantity);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: Console log result for hello]

Below is my dropdown HTML:-

```
<select class="noselecttwo form-control" name="ingredients" id="ingredients" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- Select a Ingredient -- </option>
    @foreach ($ingredients as $ingredient)
       <option id="var{{$ingredient->id}}" value="{{$ingredient->id}}">{{ $ingredient->name.' - '. $ingredient->rawMaterialUnit->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you only miss this: ` $('#ingredients').trigger('change');` This way you let JS update the UI

Comment: `$('ingredients option[value=' + element.raw_material_id + ']').prop('selected',true);` ?

Comment: @RobBiermann yes, finally! Only missed a single line, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hey @Shree, I guess yours is correct too but it doesn't work on my code. Anyway, the answer from Rob solve the problem. Thanks to you too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only missed a single line, here for those who face the same problem!

```
$('#ingredients').trigger('change');
```

This way you let JS update the UI. Thanks Rob for helping at the comment section!